# How to get error code of an exception type without raising it?

Tags: oracle, exception

Is there anyway in Oracle to get the error code associated with a user-defined exception type without that exception being actually raised?
I don't want to hard-code the code in the entire pl/sql package, and it should be persistent.

example:

```
create package body some_package is


  item_not_found exception;
  pragma exception_init(item_not_found , -20010);


  function do_something is

  begin 

    -- a select statement --

    exception when no_date_found then
    raise_application_error( [ here I need to pass the error code associated with item_not_found ], 'The item you requested was not found');

  end ;


end some_package;
```

In this example, sqlerr is not what I need.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this is possible. In my application I define all errors in an generic PL/SQL package like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Errors IS

   E_ItemNotFound CONSTANT INTEGER := -20010;
   ItemNotFound EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ItemNotFound, -20010); 

END Errors;
```

Then in exception handlers I use either the EXCEPTION or the constant error number, depending on my needs. The error messages are define in a table.

```
create table t_error_messages as 
select -20010 ERR_CODE, 'Item not found' as ERR_MESSAGE
from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks, but pragma exception_init does not accept a constant as a second argument. It must be a literal.

Comment: @Nina you are right, I corrected it.